# Why does the XMLEventReader not read XML Version=1.1

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax, xmlstreamreader

I have written a program which reads bunch of XML files and then compares them. This program works like a gem with `XML Version 1.0` but it break giving following exception with `XML version 1.1`. Can someone please help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl$NS11ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.java:889)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:554)
```

I know there is a similar quesiton available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727288/why-does-the-stax-parser-think-this-is-valid-xml-1-0-but-not-1-1). I have already download the `xercesImpl.jar:xml-apis.jar` and tried but I still get the same exception. I have downloade the zip highlighted in the image below.
[image]

EDIT 1: Posting XML file.( XML has been edited to hide client specific details)

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!-- file filenamehere -->
 <jnlp codebase="http://servername here/" href="http://servername/foldername/filename">
   <information>
     <title>something</title>
     <vendor>vernor info</vendor>
     <icon href="image here"/>
     <icon kind="something" href="impage here"/> 
   </information>
   <security> <all-permissions/> </security>
   <resources>
     <j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m" java-vm-args="-XX:PermSize=64m -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=30000"/>
     <jar href="1.jar"/>
     <jar href="2.jar"/>
     <jar href="3.jar"/>
     <jar href="4.jar"/>
     <jar href="5.jar"/>
     <jar href="6.jar" main="true"/>
     <jar href="7.jar"/>
     <jar href="8.jar"/>
     <jar href="9.jar"/>
     <jar href="0.jar"/>
     <jar href="22.jar"/>
     <jar href="11.jar"/>
     <jar href="33.jar"/>
     <jar href="44.jar"/> 
     <jar href="55.jar"/>
     <jar href="66.jar"/>
     <jar href="77.jar"/>
     <jar href="88.jar"/>
     <jar href="99.jar"/>
     <jar href="00.jar"/>
     <jar href="12.jar"/>
     <jar href="23.jar"/>
     <jar href="34.jar"/>
     <jar href="45.jar"/>
     <jar href="56.jar"/>
     <jar href="67.jar"/>
     <jar href="78.jar"/>
     <jar href="89.jar"/>
     <jar href="90.jar"/>
     <jar href="13.jar"/>
     <jar href="14.jar"/>
     <jar href="15.jar"/>
     <jar href="16.jar"/>
    <jar href="17.jar"/>
     <jar href="18.jar"/>
     <jar href="19.jar"/>
     <jar href="24.jar"/>
     <jar href="25.jar"/>
     <jar href="26.jar"/>
     <jar href="27.jar"/>
     <jar href="28.jar"/>
     <jar href="29.jar"/>
     <jar href="30.jar"/>
     <property name="org.apache.commons.logging.Log" value="org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger"/>
     <property name="someproperty3343" value="some name"/>
     <property name="log4j.configuration" value="resources/properties/something.properties"/>
     <property name="someproperty" value="true"/>
     <property name="swing.noxp" value="true"/>
     <property name="someproperty1" value="true"/>
     <property name="ssomeproperty2" value="false"/>
     <property name="someproperty3" value="true"/>
     <property name="someproperty4" value="true"/>
     <property name="ui.jws.useJWSPath" value="true"/>
     <property name="ui.jws.jwspath" value="javaws.exe"/>
     <property name="someproperty6" value="1"/>
     <property name="someproperty656" value="true"/>
     <property name="someproperty7" value="Frame"/>
     <property name="someproperty78" value="true"/>
     <property name="someproperty6B" value="true"/>
     <property name="ui.jnlpfilename" value="1.5/some.jnlp"/>
     <property name="ui.products.cdswap.setNYTimeZone" value="false"/>
     <property name="somepropertyttg" value="http://servername/foldername/ChainSaw.jnlp"/>
     <property name="someproperty89" value="false"/>
     <property name="98" value="http://servername/something/services/services"/>
     <property name="someproperty76" value="-1"/>
     <property name="someproperty54" value="http://server/Service.asmx"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows"> 
     <nativelib href="lib/winops.jar"/>
  </resources>
   <application-desc main-class="com.main.mainclass">
   <argument>-R</argument>
   <argument>parameter1</argument>
   <argument>-P</argument>
   <argument>parameter3</argument>
   <argument>-l</argument>
   <argument>windows</argument>
   <argument>-co</argument>
   <argument>parameter4</argument>
   </application-desc>
 </jnlp>
```

EDIT 2: My apologies.. i am using XMLEventReader.. initialy the heading said Stax.

Comment: Post the XML. If it's a big file and you can narrow it down to a particular section of XML, then just post that.

Comment: edited the question with the XML file..

Comment: Just one more observation.. I see that the self ending tags are the once leading to exception.. If i remove them everything works fine.. but i cannot do away with them.. i need to take them into account...