# Xerces error while processing IDocs with WSO2

Tags: wso2, idoc, wso2-esb

I have a problem processing IDocs with WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. Each time an IDoc with empty segments (which seems to be a valid IDoc) is incoming Xerces will throw an error:

```
ERROR - Axis2IDocHandler Error while processing the IDoc through the Axis engine
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:554)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMFilterIterator.hasNext(OMFilterIterator.java:54)
    at org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.idoc.util.IDoCAdapterUtils.stampArcKey(IDoCAdapterUtils.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.idoc.Axis2IDocHandler$IDocWorker.run(Axis2IDocHandler.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is likely to be a problem in the JDKs Xerces implementation as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727288/why-does-the-stax-parser-think-this-is-valid-xml-1-0-but-not-1-1/10729375#10729375)

Is there any way to setup Axis2 to use another stream reader or is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with upgrading the Xerces jar file by placing the latest version jar file under ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib directory.

Comment: I already did. I placed the xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar in that directory, but this has no effects at all! I guess the problem is that the package name of the JDK's Xerces implementation (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl) is slightly different than the original one (org.apache.xerces.impl)!